# Java - Run tasks in varying time intervals

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, thread-sleep, scheduledexecutorservice

This question is for a college assignment.
I want to run a block of code every n*2 seconds (e.g. wait 1 second and run and wait 2 seconds and run and wait 4 seconds and run, etc) up to 5 times.

I currently have something like this.

```java
int timer = 1000;
int tryCounter = 0;

while( !condition()  && counter < 5){
  doTask();
  Thread.sleep(timer);
  timer *= 2;
  counter++;
}
```

Although this works, my grade benefits from not using `Thread.sleep()`. I figured out using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a fixed rate would be one way to go but I cannot get it to work due to the fact that the interval is not actually fixed.

This is for a theoretical Distributed System with high concurrency capabilities so what matters is the high scalability.

I could get away with `Thread.sleep()` if there was really no benefit or a viable way of doing this by writing it on my report. So does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Rather than call fixed rate, you might want each run of the task to schedule the next run with a longer delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to schedule tasks with ScheduledExecutorService combined with some logic. The .schedule argument lets you specify a time unit to use. You can declare a variable that can handle the increment you are trying to do.

```
int timer = 1000;
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
           //Move your code you want to implement here
        }
    };
    //Increment your variable
    while(!condition()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            service.schedule(runnable, timer, TimeUnit.SECOND);
            timer *= 2;
        }
    }
```

Moving your code execution within the runnable block and then scheduling it within a for loop where the timer is incremented should accomplish the effect you are going for. Hope that helps!

Comment: This design does not answer the `!condition()` part of the problem and launches all threads every time.

Comment: Well.... implementing the not condition is simple enough by embedding it in a while loop (as edited above). It's not clear what your condition is, but this matches what you provided. As far as not executing every thread, I'm not sure what you don't want executed, but you can build multiple runnable blocks or even multiple ScheduledExecutorServices to separate what is run when the scheduler is called